# Repeated records in MSSQL query result

Tags: php, sql-server

I have integrated system connect with MSSQL. the system fetch all records against consignment number.consignment number is in the form of integer like (12 to 15) number digit.  The query is working fine but fetch repeated result "Processing at Origin HUB" in a rows with respect to transaction time (DATETIME column name). below is my query and screenshot.

```
SELECT ct.transactionTime,
       st.TrackingStatus Event,
       ct.consignmentNumber,
       ct.currentLocation AS LOCATION,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR, c.bookingDate, 105) BookingDate,
       CASE
            WHEN ct.stateID = '18' THEN 'Consignment Arrived At ' + ct.currentLocation
                 + ' Main Office' +
                 ' on ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, transactionTime, 105)
            WHEN ct.stateID = '1' THEN ' Conginment has been Booked on ' +
                 CONVERT(NVARCHAR, c.bookingdate, 105)
                 + ' in ' + ct.currentLocation
            WHEN ct.stateID = '2' OR ct.stateID = '3' OR ct.stateID = '4' THEN
                 'Processing at Origin HUB'
            WHEN ct.stateID in ('5','6','7') THEN
                 'Reached at Destination HUB'
            WHEN ct.stateID = '8' THEN
                 'Shipment on route '
                 + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, transactionTime, 105)
                 + ' in ' + ct.currentLocation
            WHEN ct.stateID = '9' THEN
                 'Consignment has been MAWB - Manifested AWB Number: '
                 + ct.mawbnumber + ' on ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, transactionTime, 105)
                 + ' in ' + ct.currentLocation
            WHEN ct.stateID = '10' THEN (
                     SELECT 'Consignment has been "' + ct.reason
                        --
                        + ' '
                        + '" Received By "' + (
                            CASE
                                 WHEN rc.receivedBy IS NULL THEN ''
                                 ELSE rc.receivedBy
                            END
                        ) + '" Dated: ' + (
                            CASE
                                 WHEN ct.stateID = '10' THEN LEFT(rc.deliveryDate, 10)
                            END
                        ) + (
                            CASE
                                 WHEN rc.time IS NULL THEN ''
                                 ELSE RIGHT(rc.time, 8)
                            END
                        )
                        + '" '
                 FROM   runsheetconsignment rc
                 WHERE  ct.consignmentnumber = rc.consignmentnumber
                 AND ct.runsheetnumber = rc.runsheetnumber
             )
        WHEN ct.stateID = '15' THEN 'Consignment has been ' + ct.reason
             + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, transactionTime, 105) +
             ' in ' + ct.currentLocation
   END Detail
    FROM Consignment_Tracking_View ct
    INNER JOIN Consignment c
        ON  ct.consignmentNumber = c.consignmentNumber
    INNER JOIN MNP_ConsginmentTrackingStatus st
        ON  ct.stateID = st.StatusID
    WHERE c.consignmentNumber = '591091000000051' and c.consignerAccountNo not in ('4B45','7240','4H86','4H87','4H88','4B87','7240','4B45','4H91','4H89','4H90','4F47')
    ORDER BY ct.transactionTime desc
```

Please help me out.

[imagetracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fg8m.png)

Comment: Anyone help will be very helpful .

Comment: Records are not duplicate, Datetime column has different value

Comment: Thanks for your message. i want to show single record of "Processing at Origin HUB". what will i do?

Comment: you mean one record for each status?

Comment: If you see image there are 3 records "Processing at Origin HUB" i want to show only one .

Answer (score 0):

Records are not duplicate, Datetime column has different value, convert that column data to only date by cast : `CAST(column as Date)` and then **if required only then apply distinct** in select statement.

To get Status wise single record as per your comment then use PARTITION BY as below:

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT [DateTime],
    [Status],
    Location,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Status],Location ORDER BY Location) AS PartNo
    From TableName
)

SELECT
    *
FROM T WHERE PartNo=1
```

Comment: CAST(column as Date) display blank in column.

Comment: what do you mean by "T" ? i don't understand these query. can you please clarify?

Comment: as you required per status and location single row. you can achieve your result with help of above statement

Comment: will i use above statement as it is? just change names with my one.

Comment: i have given solution from the image output

Comment: it display blank. no records fetch after use this statement. can you do something more if you can?